# Optimal parameters not found for my curve fitting

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Hello I have a problem to fit some data with Python. I just begin to fit my data with Python so I have some problems... This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import *
from numpy import linalg as LA
def f(x,a,b,c):
    return a*np.power(x,b)+c

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79])
y = np.array([7200,7925,8050,8200,8000,7550,7500,6800,6400,8150,6566,6280,6105,5963,5673,5495,5395,4800,4550,4558,4228,4087,3951,3817,3721,3612,3498,3416,3359,3269,3163,3241,2984,4475,2757,2644,2555,2600,3163,2720,2630,2543,2454,2441,2389,2339,2293,2261,2212,2180,2143,2450,2065,2032,1994,1960,1930,1897,1870,1838,1821,1785,1763,1741,1718,1689,1676,1662,1635,1635,1667,1633,1617,1615,1599,1581,1565,1547,1547])
params, extras = curve_fit(f, x, y)
plt.plot(x,y, 'o')
plt.plot(x, f(x, params[0], params[1], params[2]))
plt.title('Fit')
plt.legend(['data','fit'],loc='best')
plt.show()
```

And actually I want to fit my data with a function `f(x) = a*x^b + c` where I am looking for the best values of a, b and c to fit my data.

Do you know where there is something which is wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How confident are you that the underlying model is a power law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three caveats :

- your model is not very good.
- it diverge in x=0 : don't take first points.
- you must give initial parameter estimations.

An exemple:

```
p0=[50000,-1,0]
x=x[10:]
y=y[10:]
params, cov = curve_fit(f, x, y,p0) #params=[3.16e+04  -5.83e-01  -1.00e+03]
plt.plot(x,y, 'o')
plt.plot(x, f(x, *params))
plt.title('Fit')
plt.legend(['data','fit'],loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: fit]

You can estimate the quality of the model by

```
In [178]: np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))/params
Out[178]: array([ 0.12066005, -0.12537714, -0.53450057])
```

which shows that the estimation of error on parameters is greater than 10%.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the function you use for fitting. Consider using something like

```
def f(x, a, b, c):
  return a*x + b*np.power(x, 2) + c
```

**EDIT:** accidentally posted the original function instead of the one I wanted to suggest.

Comment: Sorry but what is the difference between my function : def f(x,a,b,c):
    return a*np.power(x,b)+c ?

Comment: @PaulHain sorry I accidentally posted your original function again (must have mixed up my shells). I corrected it and added the 2nd order polynomial I wanted to suggest in the first place.